# Regex for not allowing special characters

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, knockout.js

```
if ((new RegExp("[^0-9A-Z]{5}")).test(self.accountVerInfo.mobileVerifyId())) {
    return show_notification('error', 'Error', 'Please Enter Valid OTP');
}
```

I want to restrict the special characters and also the length should be 5 characters. When I enter `. /` it's being allowed.

Comment: To restrict to 5 chars: `^[0-9A-Z]{5}$`

Comment: my need is: when i enter special characters it should show error

here when i enter 5 characters and also . and / its accepting

it doesn't accept those.

Comment: no its not working If the mobileverifyId =ABC45. it doesnot accept

Comment: if(/^[a-zA-Z0-9- ]*$/.test(<your string>) == false) { }  .. check this

Comment: add @Rory mentioned code with check result that as true or false

Comment: thnk u its working............

Answer (score 0):

If you break down your current if statement:

```
if ((new RegExp("[^0-9A-Z]{5}")).test(self.accountVerInfo.mobileVerifyId())) {
    return show_notification('error', 'Error', 'Please Enter Valid OTP');
}
```

- check reg expr:
- if there are exactly 5 characters that are not allowed
- matches the ID
- show error

your check `[^0-9A-Z]{5}` is:

- `[^0-9A-Z]` - any character that is not a number or an uppercase letter
- `{5}` exactly 5 of them

So if you enter 'a' - it will pass, but if you enter 'abcde', it will fail.

You appear to have two requirements:  it should *pass* if:

- is exactly 5 characters
- is not a special character

rather than a negative check for not what you want, change it to what you do want:

- is exactly 5 characters
- is a number or uppercase letter

number or uppercase = `[0-9A-Z]`
5 chars is `{5}`

You then also need to check the whole ID, not just whether it contains that (otherwise `. ABCDE\` would pass), so you add `^` and `$` for start-of and end-of string - these go at the start/end of the regex:

```
^[0-9A-Z]{5}$
```

but this is now a check for what is allowed, rather than what is not allowed, so also reverse your if:

```
if (!(new RegExp("^[0-9A-Z]{5}$")).test(self.accountVerInfo.mobileVerifyId())) {
  return show_notification('error', 'Error', 'Please Enter Valid OTP');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

^[0-9a-zA-Z]{5}$

this regex expression will accept 5 characters(uppercase or lower case)/numbers no special character.